# Better way to call methods based on conditions

Tags: c#, methods, sqldatareader

I have a code snippet where I am calling my database and returning data in the form of DataReader. This is based on the params whether a stored proc is used to call or  a plain text is used. Something like this:

```
IDataReader dataReader = null;

if (commandType == CommandType.StoredProcedure)
{
   dataReader = GetReaderByProc(proc, parameters);
}
else if (commandType == CommandType.Text)
{
   dataReader = GetReaderByText(text);
}
```

where `commandType` is `System.Data.CommandType`

Now this works absolutely fine. But I am curious, in such code scenarios is there a better way to implement this.

Can there be more elegant or a better way where I can call methods based on a condition?

Comment: I'd suggest using an ORM like Dapper.

Comment: Dapper was one option, but then in an existing application, where I cannot use Dapper as of now, what are my options?

Comment: This seems unnecessary. Although we can't see what `GetReaderByProc` and `GetReaderByText` do, query parameters are the only visible difference and `CommandType.Text` can use parameters just the same.  Why does there have to be a difference?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `dictionary` to hold the key (`commandType`) and value of different `Func<>` and then simply get the `func` using the key and execute it.

```
      public static Dictionary < string, Func<string, parameters, IDataReader> dbMethods = 
                           new Dictionary<string, Func<string, parameters, IDataReader>();

         public static void CreateMethodDictionary()
         {                
            dbMethods.Add(CommandType.StoredProcedure, GetReaderByProc);
            dbMethods.Add(CommandType.Text, GetReaderByText);
         }
```

And then you can invoke it like:

```
IDataReader dataReader = dbMethods[commandType].Invoke(proc, parameters);
```

This does assume that both your calling functions take in the same parameters (which is not the case currently) and return the same object.

Looking at the code though your text query should also take in parameters since parameterized queries should be the norm.